# replace special symbols on windows

Tags: r, regex, r-markdown

Students commonly paste assignment questions from a pdf or word document into Rmarkdown. However, the pasted text often has non-ascii characters for bullets, quotes, etc. I have used `gsub` in the past as part of a function to replace such characters and that seemed to work fine but I'm running into problems now again.

The first line in each pair shown below works on macOS, Linux, and Windows. However, non-ascii characters are not allowed in code to be included in an R package. The 2nd line in each pair works on macOS and Linux but not on Windows.

It would be great to have a general approach to deal with these type of characters that does not involve simply deleting them.

```
gsub("•", "*", "A big dot •")
gsub("\xE2\x80\xA2", "*", "A big dot •")

gsub("…", "...", "Some small dots …")
gsub("\xE2\x80\xA6", "...", "Some small dots …")

gsub("–", "-", "A long-dash –")
gsub("\xE2\x80\x93", "-", "A long-dash –")

gsub("’", "'", "A curly single quote ’")
gsub("\xE2\x80\x99", "'", "A curly single quote ’")

gsub("‘", "'", "A curly single quote ‘")
gsub("\xE2\x80\x98", "'", "A curly single quote ‘")

gsub("”", '"', "A curly double quote ”")
gsub("\xE2\x80\x9D", '"', "A curly double quote ”")

gsub("“", '"', "A curly double quote “")
gsub("\xE2\x80\x9C", '"', "A curly double quote “")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check the hex encoding of a character using the `Encoding` function:

```
x <- c("•", "…", "–", "’", "‘", "”", "“")
y <- x

Encoding(y) <- "bytes"

> x
[1] "•" "…" "–" "’" "‘" "”" "“"

> cat(y)
\x95 \x85 \x96 \x92 \x91 \x94 \x93
```

We can then include the hex codes in your `gsub`'s:

```
gsub("•", "*", "A big dot •")
gsub("[\x95\xE2\x80\xA2]", "*", "A big dot •")

gsub("…", "...", "Some small dots …")
gsub("[\x85\xE2\x80\xA6]", "...", "Some small dots …")

gsub("–", "-", "A long-dash –")
gsub("[\x96\xE2\x80\x93]", "-", "A long-dash –")

gsub("’", "'", "A curly single quote ’")
gsub("[\x92\xE2\x80\x99]", "'", "A curly single quote ’")

gsub("‘", "'", "A curly single quote ‘")
gsub("[\x91\xE2\x80\x98]", "'", "A curly single quote ‘")

gsub("”", '"', "A curly double quote ”")
gsub("[\x94\xE2\x80\x9D]", '"', "A curly double quote ”")

gsub("“", '"', "A curly double quote “")
gsub("[\x93\xE2\x80\x9C]", '"', "A curly double quote “")
```

Also with `stri_trans_general` from `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_general(x, "ascii")
# [1] "•"   "..." "-"   "'"   "'"   "\""  "\""
```

This seems to not work for `"•"`, but works for the rest.

Note that I have only tested this solution on Windows and not other OS.

Comment: This looks really useful @avid_userR! `stri_trans_general` may do what I need (need some more testing. I tried the "big dot" `gsub("[\x95\xE2\x80\xA2]", "*", "A big dot •")` but it doesn't seem to work on Windows or macOS. Can you confirm it works on your system?

Comment: @Vincent It does work on my machine and I have Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit. When you `cat("•")` does it show `"\x95"`?

Comment: It does. I double checked my code and noticed I didn't wrap the codes in [...]. When that was added it seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: @avid_userR Any comments on the answer/edit I just posted? I could turn the 2nd part into a new question if more appropriate.

Comment: @Vincent I'm sorry what is the 2nd part?

Comment: stringi::stri_trans_general works well on windows systems with US language settings but on a system with Chinese language settings the code shown below does not return the desired result which is just 夹. Not sure what the solution is.

stringi::stri_trans_general("夹", "ascii")
> stringi::stri_trans_general("夹", "ascii")
[1] " 1/4D"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that on systems with non-US language settings `gsub("[\x95\xE2\x80\xA2]", "*", "A big dot •")` can cause errors (see e.g., below).

```
> gsub("[\x95\xE2\x80\xA2]", "*", "A big dot •") 
Error in gsub("[曗€", "*", "A big dot <U+2022>") : 
  invalid regular expression '[曗€', reason 'Missing ']''
```

The following, however, does work well.

```
gsub("\u2022", "*", "A big dot •")
gsub("\u2026", "...", "Some small dots …")
gsub("\u2013", "-", "A long-dash –")
gsub("\u2019", "'", "A curly single quote ’")
gsub("\u2018", "'", "A curly single quote ‘")
gsub("\u201D", '"', "A curly double quote ”")
gsub("\u201C", '"', "A curly double quote “")
```

Also, `stringi::stri_trans_general` works well on systems with US language settings but on a system with Chinese language settings the code shown below does not return the desired result which is just 夹. Not sure what the solution is.

```
stringi::stri_trans_general("夹", "ascii")
> stringi::stri_trans_general("夹", "ascii")
[1] " 1/4D"
```